# Google Analytics Data API (ga4) obtain email or username current user who call

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

in universal analytics you can obtain easily the username, you receive the username in a basic call, I use that username so while I migrate to GA4 I wonder where is that data, I can consume severals endpoints but the most close was Account.UserLinks but that retrieve all user linked with an account but not say which user am I. I try add different scopes but nothing, any ideas?

scopes used

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Also Accounts don't provide that data

```
{
  "name": "accounts/6666",
  "createTime": "2018-11-16T18:27:26Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-08-13T21:17:12.851Z",
  "displayName": "Dummy",
  "regionCode": "PR"
}
```

I already know how obtain from universal but I only want use GA4 new api
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get the signed in user's profile information using the [Google Sign-In JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people) or the new [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference).

Comment: and for backend?